# Is it possible to map a one to many relationship on a Ext.data.Model

Tags: extjs

I have a model looking something like this:

```
Ext.define('Person', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
         {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'age',  type: 'int'}
     ]
 });
```

That is used by a store called `peopleStore`. If I change the name or the age of a person through my UI and invoke the `sync` method on `peopleStore` the method is executed properly and the change is persisted into my database. The problem is that in my database each person has many books, and if I change the books of a person (by modifing the peopleStore variable through the UI) then I can't execute the sync method, probably because the store doesn't see that as a change. The table `book` has the columns `name` and `person_id`.

PS: I know that it doesn't execute the sync method properly because otherwise it would eventually end up in either the `success` or the `failure` callback methods but it doesn't.

Comment: Hey, check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rat It should explain your concern about OneToMany relationship

Answer (score 0):

I modified the book list in the wrong way. This is the correct way assuming that in the `Person` entity class there is a `List<Book> books` property.

```
var person=peopleStore.getAt(personIndex);
var bookList=person.get('books');
var newBookList=booklist.slice(0, bookList.length);
newBoolList.push('new book');
person.set('books', newBookList);
```

Then it is possible to invoke the `sync` method.